# how do I insert a different icon for each widgets

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

how do I insert a different icon for each widgets?

```
[
            'type'          => 'progress_white',
            'class'         => 'card mb-2',
            'progressClass' => 'progress-bar bg-primary',
            'value'         => $userCount,
            'description'   => 'Utenti registrati.',
            'progress'      => (int)$userCount/10*100, // integer
            'hint'          => 'Numero di utenti registrati al portale.',
        ],
```

the html part is this this part below

```
<div class="{{ $widget['wrapperClass'] ?? 'col-sm-6 col-md-4' }}">
<div class="{{ $widget['class'] ?? 'card' }}">
<div class="card-body">
  @if (isset($widget['value']))
  <div class="text-value">{!! $widget['value'] !!}</div>
  @endif
```

......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way with the default widgets you will ave to create your own.

```
@if(isset($widget['icon']))
   <div class="text-right" style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:15px;font-size: 40px;color: {{ $widget['icon_color'] ?? 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)' }}">
      <span class="{{ $widget['icon'] }}"></span>
   </div>
@endif
```

Put that within the card-body class. Styling might need to be changed a little bit.

Other option is Backpack uses a new theme based on CoreUI. Can look at the documentation for CoreUI, or take a look at the source for the theme at https://backstrap.net

Comment: I only have one question but overwriting items from the dashboard works like this:
the path is this:
resources \ views \ vendor \ backpack \ base \
should the file to be overwritten progress_white.blade.php be put here? thanks

Answer (score 0):

What kind of icons do you want? If you use icon set like material icon or awesome icon, you can  pass your icon name and use it in "i" tag like this:

```
"icon" => "fa fa user"
```

and in your blade:

```
<i class"{{$widget['icon']}}"></i>
```

Comment: 'icon' => 'fa fa-user', 
it works for me but thanks anyway
very nice